# Tell me how to send the Json request

Tags: android, json, http, connection

> I am sending the json request code give the error Is there any way how
>   to send the json request with authentication.this Code give the Error
>   in filenotfound "http://api.seatseller.travel/blockTicket"
>    //st =
>   json object

```
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
         JSONObject jsonParam = st;//JSON 
         HttpURLConnection request=null; 
        OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer("tOzL5hTkSz9KiA2RIAECW4g7Uq","cj8HLPmBKnRAsffLe5qpQIZ9Y");
        consumer.setTokenWithSecret(null, null); //i pass token as access token as a null as my server dont need it.

        URL url = new URL("http://api.seatseller.travel/blockTicket");
          request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        request.setDoOutput(true);   
        request.setRequestMethod("GET"); 
        request.setUseCaches(false);  
        request.setConnectTimeout(10000);  
        request.setReadTimeout(10000);  
        request.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");   

        request.setRequestProperty("Host", "android.schoolportal.gr");


        consumer.sign(request);
        request.connect();
        OutputStreamWriter out = new   OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
        out.write(jsonParam.toString());
        out.close();  
        int HttpResult =request.getResponseCode();  
        if(HttpResult ==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){  
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(  
                    request.getInputStream(),"utf-8"));  
            String line = null;  
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
                sb.append(line + "\n");  
            }  
            br.close();  

            System.out.println(""+sb.toString());  

        }else{  
                System.out.println(request.getResponseMessage());  
        }  
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {  

             e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    catch (IOException e) {  

        e.printStackTrace();  
        } 
     catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: please update your question with error description, without it it's nothing

Comment: We don't know and we can't guess what that `st` parameter is.

Comment: hello Sir ..st is json object ..

Comment: this code send the file not found exception...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List<NameValuePair> params) {


        try {
            if(method == "POST"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

Then Create AsyncTask Class to upload data to server.Then add this code.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String message="";        
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1", value1));

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SERVER_URL,
                "POST", params);
        try {
                message=json.getString("message");
                Log.e("msg",message);

        }catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message ;
    }
```

value1 send to server.

Comment: This code is working fine you just need to create AsyncTask and add second code.This one for send POST variable.You have to change it to GET.

Comment: Dear i have try lots of type of way to send the request

Comment: Ok before that make sure your server is working properly.You can use CURL request to check the server.

Answer (score 0):

look mr...dhiraj kakran  i am also suffering the same problem in the android sdk itself one bug is there i mean restriciton  on network  request in the case of post request using oauthentication  we cant oauth sign in the post request using HttpUrlConnection for sepeciallly post sign method using the oauth we use default HttpClient class  i am giving the solution for this now you can get response through this class best of luck

```
public class BlockTicketPostOauth extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    String response;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(BusPassengerInfo.this);
        pd.setMessage("wait continue to payment....");
        pd.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String ul ="http://api.seatseller.travel/blockTicket";

        String  JSONPayload=params[0]; // THIS IS THE JSON DATA WHICH YOU WANT SEND TO THE SERVER 
        Integer result = 0;
        try {

            OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(YOUR CONSUMER KEY,YOUR CONSUMER SECRETE KEY); consumer.setTokenWithSecret(null, null);

            /* create Apache HttpClient */
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            /* Httppost Method */
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(ul);

            // sign the request
            consumer.sign(httppost);

            // send json string to the server
            StringEntity paras =new StringEntity(JSONPayload);

            //seting the type of input data type
            paras.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));

            httppost.setEntity(paras);

            HttpResponse httpResponse= httpclient.execute(httppost);

            int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            Log.i("response json:","status code is:"+statusCode);
            Log.i("response json:","status message?:"+httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());

            /* 200 represents HTTP OK */
            if (statusCode ==  200) {
                /* receive response as inputStream */
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                response = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                Log.i("response json:","json response?:"+response);

                Log.i("response block ticket :","status block key:"+response);

                result = 1; // Successful
            } else{
                result = 0; //"Failed to fetch data!";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("response error", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return result; //"Failed to fetch data!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {

        if(pd.isShowing()){
            pd.dismiss();
        }
        /* Download complete. Lets update UI */
        if(result == 1){


            Toast.makeText(BusPassengerInfo.this,"response is reult suceess:"+response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //allowing the customer to going to the payment gate way

        }else{
            Log.e("response", "Failed to fetch data!");
            Toast.makeText(BusPassengerInfo.this,"response is reult fail",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```